# SQL query fetching

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is the data which is retrieved for a particular `NO`.

```
id    color    no
5939  Black     1
5959  Silver    1
7900  Blue      1
7593  Red       1
```

The table has `Black` so i have to return only id `5939`. If my table doesn't have a record for `Black` then i have to return Silver ID 5959, same for Blue and Red.

Note : I should have only one input parameter to my SQL query and that is `NO`

Comment: how did you specify the order relation between colour (first black then silver, etc? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL Server answer

```
SELECT TOP 1 id,color,no
FROM YourTable
WHERE no=@no
ORDER BY CASE Color 
             WHEN 'Black'  THEN 1 
             WHEN 'Silver' THEN 2 
             WHEN 'Blue'   THEN 3 
             WHEN 'Red'    THEN 4 
          END
```

Or a more portable answer

```
WITH T
     As (SELECT id,
                color,
                no,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CASE Color 
                                                  WHEN 'Black' THEN 1 
                                                  WHEN 'Silver' THEN 2
                                                  WHEN 'Blue' THEN 3 
                                                  WHEN 'Red' THEN 4 
                                              END) AS RN
         FROM   YourTable
         WHERE  no = @no)
SELECT id,
       color,
       no
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin... I need to add to one thing.. Actually the table contains many colors and many rows so it wont be ideal to specify every color in the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like "select * from table where no = ? limit 1". The keyword LIMIT depends on your database, for DB2 it would be "select * from table where no = ? fetch first 1 rows only".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that will return the first Id for NO.

```
SELECT MIN(Id)
  FROM Table a
 WHERE No = ?
```